Vue3 OnsenUI の v-ons-tabbar にて v-ons-tab の長押し（hold）でもタブ切り替えをさせたい
以下のバージョンを利用しています。
vue.js: 3.3.4
vue-onsenui:3.0.0
cordova-cli: 12.0.0
cordova-android: 12.0.0
Vue3 のOnsenUIにてCordovaを利用したスマートフォンアプリを作っています。
タブ操作が必要で、v-ons-tabbar （もしくはv-slot + v-ons-tab）にてタブの実装はできていますが、長押し（Hold）でもクリックと同様の挙動（タブ切り替え）をできるようにしなければなりません。
一つ方針として考えたのは、長押しイベントを補足するvueのカスタムディレクティブ（v-holdと仮称）を作成し、各ons-tabに設定するということでした。
しかし
v-ons-tabbar を利用すると、v-ons-tabはOnsenUI内でDOMを自動生成してしまうため、v-holdディレクティブを設定することができません。
一方で、v-slot + v-ons-tab では、個別にons-tab要素を指定できるため、v-holdディレクティブの設定はできましたが、受け取ったイベント内で、どのようにjsでタブ切り替えを制御できるのかがわかっておりません。
もしご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらヒントだけでもいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

タブバーを自作することで解決しました。
